# Present a modal landscape View Controller from a portrait View Controller

Tags: ios, ios4, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I've got a portrait only VC that presents a landscape only VC. I'm struggling to see how it I can make it work. I've had some luck with calling an animation rotating the modal VC after it is presented but that looks a bit dodgy.

I'm stuck with iOS 4.3 so no storyboards.

what I would like is something like...

```
[landscapeVC setOrentation:UIDeviceOrentaionLanscape];
[portraitVC presentModalViewController:landscapeVC Animated:YES];
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this in portraitVC's viewDidLoad method and in shouldautorotate method:

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight animated:NO];
 [[self view] setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320)];
 [[self view] setCenter:CGPointMake(160, 240)];
 [[self view] setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2)];
```

Comment: After a few test it turns out that both the VC are nested in another VC that has orientation locked to portrait. You don't know if I can call the "shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation..." method on the master VC?